# Adding google maps markers by an address instead of coordinates?

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, street-address

In my Flex project, can I add markers by its address instead of this:

```
var myGeographicCoordinates:LatLng = new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);
```

for example add marker by "Paris, France"

Comment: A detail blog http://goo.gl/d8w1J0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read [Google's developer manual on Geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/services.html#Geocoding).  It explains how to convert an address to a geolocation.  I recommend you try looking at the Dev manual/API/Google before posting here.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499862/how-to-geocode-an-address-into-lat-long-with-google-maps) for an actual code example.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can do so directly. Instead you need to geocode the address and then use a `LatLng` to store the result.

Check out google's geocoding api here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/