# How to geocode an address into lat/long with Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to be able to plot several companies on a google map and understand I need to geocode these.

I also have the code below that plot's multiple markers on a map.

How can I Geocode several company addresses (using the following address as the first example) and incorporate it into the current code I have?

I really need someone's help as I can't make sense of the Google documentation as well as incorporating it with what I already have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could use [google's geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to obtain coordinates of your post codes

EDIT: I don't really like you changing the sense of the question like that but ok. Please try sth like that (its not tested):

```
// Creating an array that will contain the coordinates 
// for New York, San Francisco, and Seattle
var places = [];

// Adding a LatLng object for each city
//places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.756, -73.986));
//places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(37.775, -122.419));
//places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(47.620, -122.347));
//places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(-22.933, -43.184));
var result;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=your+code&sensor=false",true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
       result = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');
if (result.status == "OK") {
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(result.results[0].geometry.location.lat, result.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
places.push(location);
```

this should probably work, despite possible minor errors.

EDIT2: I have just now found [simpler solution](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding):

```
// Creating an array that will contain the coordinates 
// for New York, San Francisco, and Seattle
var places = [];

// Adding a LatLng object for each city
//places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.756, -73.986));
//places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(37.775, -122.419));
//places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(47.620, -122.347));
//places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(-22.933, -43.184));
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "your+code"}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        //map: map,
        //position: results[0].geometry.location
    //});
    places.push(results[0].geometry.location);
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've no idea of where to start with it let alone merge it with the current code I have.

Comment: Look at the site I have provided link to and:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp
, just build your request like:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=SW1A+0AA
eval json response from google and you are good to go

Comment: oops forgot about sensor in geocode request: maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=SW1A+0AA&sensor=false

Comment: Thanks for the edit. where would that fit into my current code?

Comment: you should put these results instead of hard-coded array with latLng objects (places), I will edit answer once more to show it more clearly

Comment: Thanks, does that code just replace the line starting - "creating an array that will..." down to (just above) "creating a variable that will..."? Also, where it says "your+code" can I put in a php variable that is grabbing a postcode from my cms?

Comment: exactly, this geocodes one address, so to add more put it in a simple loop (google it if you don't know how), and yes, you can put a variable there, as long as it contains proper string (not sure if this geocoder allows spaces, it's safer to put + instead of space)

Comment: Ok thanks. Not sure how to do that but I may open it up to another question. Thanks very much for all the help.

Comment: if it doesn't work, please debug it and see what status geocoding returns and if you pass it a proper code, also see if the status is OK whether a LatLng object is created and passed to marker constructor properly

Comment: I have the looping through multiple markers slightly further down in the original code. Would that do it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3687/discussion-between-slawekwin-and-rob)